# How to join two values from different columns of the same table in Sqlite3?

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I have first_name and last_name column in the same table. I want to join and put them in a new column called full_name still in the same table. How can I do it? I've googled it but found only joining two or more columns from different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *concatenate* them, not *join* them.  So, use the concatenation operator:

```
select (first_name || ' ' || last_name) as full_name
from t;
```

SQLite does not support generated columns.  But if you want `full_name` to be available for more than one query, then you can define a view:

```
create view v_t as
    select t.*, (first_name || ' ' || last_name) as full_name
    from t;
```